# Internal logic characterization of closed subobjects for a Lawvere-Tierney topology

Tags: topos-theory

I am trying to understand the relation between Lawvere-Tierney topologies and the internal logic of toposes. For a closure operator $\overline{-}$ I am trying to prove that a subobject $A$ of an object $E$ is closed (with respect to the given closure operator) if and only if ${(\forall e, e' \in E)(e \in A \wedge  \overline{e = e'} \Rightarrow e'\in A)}$.

Is it true?

(It seems intuitive to me but I cannot prove it.)

Comment: As written, with $e \in A$ appearing twice, the statement is a tautology. Perhaps, the $e \in A$ to the right of the $\Rightarrow$ symbol should be replaced with $e' \in A$.

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Comment: A similar internal logic statement which should be equivalent to $A$ being closed would be: $(\forall e : E)(\overline{e \in A} \rightarrow e \in A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true.
Consider the trivial closure operator that sends every subobject of $E$ to $E$ itself.
Let $A$ be the empty subobject.
Then, vacuously, $e \in A \land \overline{e = e'} \implies e' \in A$.
But $A$ is not closed if $E$ is not empty.

Comment: I wonder if there are any Lawvere-Tierney topologies for which the intuition works.

Comment: I think the intuition must be faulty. $\overline{e = e'}$ only tells you about which elements become equal after sheafification; it does not tell you about "new" elements. The closure operator is a shadow of sheafification and this example shows that there is a similar phenomenon of "new" elements in the closure.

Comment: I agree that something is wrong with my intuition. Still, what if we assume that ${\overline{empty} = empty}$?

Comment: I don’t think that works. Consider the case where $E = 1$: then equality is trivial and your condition reduces to a tautology, no matter what $A$ is.

Answer (score 3):

The correct condition for a subobject $A$ of $E$ to be closed is (the somewhat tautological):
$$\forall x : E.\ \overline{x \in A} \Rightarrow x \in A.$$

Section 6.4 of [these notes of mine](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/notes.pdf) summarize a couple of similar properties and constructions, such as the condition to be a sheaf or sheafification, all using the internal language.